# How to get the columns of table in one row?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've a db where schema is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student]([Id] [int] NULL,[Name] [varchar](255) NULL,[Mark] [int] NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Student] ([Id], [Name], [Mark]) VALUES (1, N'Medi', 10)
INSERT [dbo].[Student] ([Id], [Name], [Mark]) VALUES (2, N'Ibra', 15)
INSERT [dbo].[Student] ([Id], [Name], [Mark]) VALUES (3, N'Simo', 20)
```

So the query `select * from Student`:

| Id | Name | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Medi | 10 |
| 2 | Ibra | 15 |
| 3 | Simo | 20 |

But I want the headers in first row like this:

| Id | Name | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id | Name | Mark |
| 1 | Medi | 10 |
| 2 | Ibra | 15 |
| 3 | Simo | 20 |

In order to build up this result,

- First I want to get the columns:

I've done this with the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Student'
```

| COLUMN_NAME |
| --- |
| Id |
| Name |
| Mark |

```sql
SELECT  IIF(COLUMN_NAME='Id',COLUMN_NAME,'')Id,IIF(COLUMN_NAME='Name',COLUMN_NAME,'')Name,IIF(COLUMN_NAME='Mark',COLUMN_NAME,'') Mark
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Student'
```

| Id | Name | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id |  |  |
|  | Name |  |
|  |  | Mark |

But I want them in one row like this:

| Id | Name | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id | Name | Mark |

```sql
with cte as(
SELECT  IIF(COLUMN_NAME='Id',COLUMN_NAME,'')Id,IIF(COLUMN_NAME='Name',COLUMN_NAME,'')Name,IIF(COLUMN_NAME='Mark',COLUMN_NAME,'') Mark
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Student'
)
select * from cte where id!=''
union
select * from cte where Name!=''
union 
select * from cte where Mark!=''
```

I know it's not the right way of doing it, **BUT** How can I do that?

I want to copy the result of a query from the SSMS grid, but I don't want to use the option of copying with headers. It seems useless, but I want to challenge myself to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's surprisingly difficult to do what you want *completely* generically in T-SQL, but this works for the example:

```
DECLARE 
    @Query nvarchar(max),
    @ExtraRow nvarchar(max);

SET @Query = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.Student;'

SELECT @ExtraRow = STRING_AGG
    (
        CONCAT
        (
            CONVERT(nvarchar(max), NCHAR(13)),
            QUOTENAME(RS.[name]),
            N' = CONVERT(sql_variant, N',
            QUOTENAME(RS.[name], NCHAR(39)),
            N')'
        ),
        N','
    ) 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RS.column_ordinal)
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@Query, NULL, NULL) AS RS;

SET @Query = CONCAT
    (
        N'SELECT ', 
        @ExtraRow,
        NCHAR(13),
        N'UNION ALL',
        NCHAR(13),
        @Query
    );

PRINT @Query;
EXECUTE (@Query);
```

The dynamic SQL generated is:

```
SELECT 
[Id] = CONVERT(sql_variant, N'Id'),
[Name] = CONVERT(sql_variant, N'Name'),
[Mark] = CONVERT(sql_variant, N'Mark')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dbo.Student;
```

[*db<>fiddle* demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HbxEnpaG)

Coding challenge aside, you can set SSMS to always copy the headers in the options:

[image: SSMS Options]

Or, to sometimes copy headers or not, use the keyboard shortcuts or grid context menu:

[image: Grid context menu]